# Bitbucket, Mercurial - resolving merge conflicts when syncing a fork

Tags: merge, mercurial, bitbucket, merge-conflict-resolution, git-fork

```
master (read-only)
  |--- myFork (write)
  |--- otherFork01 (read-only)
  |--- otherFork02 (read-only)
  .
  .
  .
```

I've used Mercurial as a VCS (had to), committing to `myFork`. Now Bitbucket is letting me know that I'm a couple commits behind master - which up to now, was not an issue to resolve.

This time, however, I'm getting merge conflicts when hitting the sync-button. Unfortunately, Bitbucket does not seem to provide a way to resolve the conflict right there in its interface.

Instead, it's providing more information about how to resolve conflicts if I were using Git - which is not particularly helpful in this case.

As due to the conflicts, the merge is never performed, I can't simply pull the conflict from bitbucket to resolve it either.

I'm using TortoiseHG and created the fork through the Bitbucket interface.

I would appreciate it if somebody could help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that if you keep hitting "merge" and then "show details" in the resulting error message, you will eventually get to a detail page where hitting merge again will display you the necessary code to execute.

Not sure why they would hit it thus, though.

Comment: btw, those details aren't very clear, where should I run the first `git fetch origin $OTHER_BRANCH` ? in `master` or my conflicted branch ?